# Visual Studio Code syntax highlighting for CMakeLists.txt

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ros

I am using ROS and C++ and ROS packages have a `CMakeLists.txt` in them. I would like to have a syntax highlighting for CMakeLists.txt in visual studio code.

Unfortunately, I searched on the internet but I can't find how to do this.

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you referring to syntax highlighting? If so, you might be looking for [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake).

Comment: Yeah, I found it immeditately after posting my question :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Below is how to do it. It is quite straightforward (with an extension):

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. `CTRL+P` - Launch VS Code Quick Open
3. `ext install twxs.cmake` - Install the extension "CMake For VisualStudio Code"

I hope this will help someone else.

p.s. It is always like that. I search for a long time, I don't find an answer. Then I post the question here and I immediately find the answer.

Answer (score -1):

most easiest is to install `cmake` and `CMake Language Support` extensions. makes your life easier. you could search them and install in extension panel in vs code.